# How to get a very wide code block in Code Blocks Extension for Google Docs with little to no handiwork?

Tags: google-drive, formatting

When you copy and paste from the console output, you will often have linebreaks. You can avoid that by shifting the right border of the Code Blocks field by the length of what is left over at the right side of the page. But if you have very long lines that you still want to show without a line break, you need to draw that border many times to the right. This takes a lot of time.

How to get a very wide code block without that fiddly handiwork of shifting the border to the right many times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing this after it had been helpful for weeks, and I did not run into this easy workaround for months, widening many code blocks in many steps until any line break had vanished. That is not needed. Instead, use copy and paste.

Make a wide code block just once, in a Drive Doc that you can use to copy from.

Take a very long console output line as the widest needed code block with language *shell* and put it in a Doc that is just for style patterns. Whenever you need a wide code block, copy the wide default one from the default Doc and fill it with *Ctrl+Shift+V* in *shell* language. Afterwards, you can still change to other languages.

Leave an empty line before and after the code block to copy so that you can copy it easily.

Could look like:

[image]